# Initializing redux reducer with response from an api call

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on a livechat support application using React/Redux that support agents can use to chat with customers. The application displays a list of incoming requests in a sidebar and agents can accept requests from there. The incoming requests is gotten by making an API call/Websockets. I intend to initialize the chat request reducer with data from the API call and performing computations based on that data.

Here is how I intend to structure my reducer.

```
const initialState = {
  incomingRequests: [] // Initialized with data from API call,
  acceptedRequests: [] // Stores IDs of requests accepted by an agent
  rejectedRequests: [] // Stores IDs of request rejected by an agent
  completedRequests: [] // Stores IDs of requests completed by an agent
}
const chatRequestsReducer = (state=initialState, action) {
  // Returns new state based on action type
}
```

What is the most efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: You can do async things in your actions with libraries like redux-thunk.
Btw I'm not sure what you mean by "initializing a reducer".

Comment: I am already making use of redux thunk. When I say intialize, I mean setup the incomingRequests array to contain data fetched from an API call when the app loads.

Comment: Create an action creator that initiates the API call, then dispatch an action which sets the field?
`const initializeData = () => (dispatch) => { apiCall().then(response => {dispatch(setIncomingRequests(response.incomingRequests))}) }`

So you need two actions at least.

Comment: That is a great idea. This is a bit off topic, but what if I need to periodically make API requests to update the list. How would suggest I handle that?

Comment: maybe fetch the data the same way and create a "updateIncomingRequests" action, where you merge the new data with the state

Comment: Works perfectly. I simply dispatched the action to fetch the data from the API in the root component(the one wrapped with Provider) and I showed a loading screen during data fetch.

Comment: Do you have any idea of how to do the same thing but instead get the data from a websocket.